# A question on Selberg's sieve

Tags: nt.number-theory

If we define 
$$D=D(z,w)=\sum_{d\vert P_z, d\leq w}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}$$
$$\lambda(k)=\frac{k}{D} \sum_{k\vert d,d\vert P_z , d\leq w}\frac{\mu(\frac{d}{k})\mu(d)}{\phi(d)}$$
$$p(d)=\sum_{lcm(d_1,d_2)=d }\lambda(d_1)\lambda(d_2)$$

In other words, we're dealing with the Selberg Sieve,  is it possible to say, for the Möbius function $\mu(d)$, that
$$\sum_{d\vert P_z} \vert \mu(d) \vert \leq \sum_{d\vert P_z} \vert p(d)\vert$$

Comment: Notice, of course, that if $d$ is not squarefree, then $\mu(d)=\p(d)=0.$  If $d$ is squarefree, then $\vert \mu(d) \vert =1$.  We could ask if $\vert p(d) \vert$ is usually bigger than $1$.  If $d$ is prime, then
 $$\vert p(d) \vert=\vert \lambda (d) \vert= \frac{k}{D} \sum_{k\vert d, d\vert P_z, d\leq w}\frac{1}{\phi(d)}$$
so, given our definition of $D$, how much is lost when we further restrict $k\vert d$ as it appears in our definition of $\vert \lambda (d) \vert$?

Comment: Consider that the sign of $\lambda(d_1) \lambda(d_2)$ is exactly that of $\mu(d)$.  Thus, if we factor that out, we get
$$p(d)=\mu(d) \sum_{lcm(d_1, d_2)}\vert \lambda(d_1) \lambda(d_2) \vert.$$
Now, it looks as though $\vert \lambda(d) \vert$ is an increasing function over squarefree $d$, any ideas of how to show that?